# Can missing else blocks be globally ignored in Istanbul

Tags: istanbul

I have code that has multiple `if` statements but no corresponding `else` statements. I have been adding `/* istanbul ignore else */` individually for all these `if` statements in order to ignore the corresponding missing `else` blocks. Is there are way to ignore all the missing `else` statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the current [Istanbul documentation](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul):

1. The way to ignore an ["else path" coverage](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/blob/master/ignoring-code-for-coverage.md) is: `(/* istanbul ignore else  */`
2. In [Ideas for Later](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/blob/master/misc/config/istanbul-config.json) the author is considering adding " `"default-excludes": true,"` to the configuration file.

BOTTOM LINE:

it appears that in the current version, you must add `/* istanbul ignore else  */` to each block you wish to exclude.